# A host error has occurred during startup operation of App Fuctions inside Kubernetes

Tags: c#, kubernetes, azure-functions, kubernetes-pod, azure-servicebus-queues

I have deployed an Azure App Function project to AKS and have set all of the correct start variables required to run the app functions. It is continually failing during start up with the below error.

| Message | Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'hostingEnvironment') |
| --- | --- |
| Exception type | System.ArgumentNullException |
| Failed method | DryIoc.ReflectionFactory+<>c__DisplayClass21_0.b__1 |

```
Inner exception System.ArgumentNullException handled at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod:
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentExtensions.IsDevelopment (Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.StorageWebJobsBuilderExtensions+<>c.<AddAzureStorage>b__0_5 (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage, Version=3.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage, Version=3.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage\StorageWebJobsBuilderExtensions.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage, Version=3.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 74)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigureNamedOptions`2.Configure (Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=3.1.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create (Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=3.1.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.WebJobsOptionsFactory`1.Create (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.26.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.26.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Hosting\OptionsFormatter\WebJobsOptionsFactory.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.26.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 37)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1+<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Get>b__0 (Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=3.1.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd (Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=3.1.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.Get (Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=3.1.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.get_Value (Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=3.1.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Queues.Triggers.QueueTriggerAttributeBindingProvider..ctor (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage, Version=3.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage, Version=3.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage\Queues\Triggers\QueueTriggerAttributeBindingProvider.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage, Version=3.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 42)
```

Comment: post your code. Function signature esp.

Comment: Did you mean you are using [Azure Functions on Kubernetes with KEDA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-kubernetes-keda)?